# Improving the readability of Capybara tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm writing a rspec/capybara test that ensures input fields in a form display the correct validations.

I'm concerned that my code is not very readable. How can I refactor this to make sure that it's readable?

```
describe "#page" do
  context "form validation" do
    1.upto(4) do |index|
      it "throws correct validation error when #{5-index} field(s) is (are) empty" do
        login(page_path)
        fill_in_form(index)
        find('.button').trigger(:click)
        expect(all('.form-error').count).to eq 5-index
        all('.form-error')[-1...index-5].each do |error|
          expect(error.text).to eq "#{@inputs[5-index][:error_message]} is required"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


def fill_in_form(number_of_fields)
  (0).upto(number_of_fields-1) do |i|
    fill_in(@inputs[i][:name], :with => (@inputs[i][:value]))
  end
end

def login(path)
  visit(path)
  # redirected to login
  acceptance_login(@user)
  visit(path)
  # input fields
  @inputs = [
    {name: 'first_name', error_message: "First name is not valid", value: "John"},
    {name: 'last_name', error_message: "Last name is not valid", value: "Doe"},
    {name: 'company', error_message: "Company name is not valid", value: "My company"},
    {name: 'role', error_message: "Role is not valid", value: "Developer"},
    {name: 'phone', error_message: "Phone number is not valid", value: "(800) 492-1111"}
  ]
end
```

Comment: Empty lines between groups of related method calls is one step towards better readability. Dense chunks of code like that are hard to read.

Comment: One thing is to use the count options Capybara provides rather than using an eq matcher on the count (which will lead to flaky tests since it prevents waiting/retrying).    Replace the expect and all(..).each with   -   `all('.form-error', count: 5-index).each do |error| ... end`  which will do the check for the correct number of elements in the `all` statement (waiting if needed).  If you just wanted to check that the correct number of elements are there then it would be `expect(page).to have_css('.form-error', count: 5-index)` rather than the expect(all(...).count).to eq ... you're using.

Comment: take a look at https://cucumber.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate out the login stuff into a before block, and adding some extra line breaks will make an immediate difference.

Reconsider the need to loop over the form all those times. Feature tests are expensive and slow, so use them as an overview to ensure error handling has been implemented on the form.

The specific implementation of the error messages, in all the relevant situations, I would leave to unit tests as they are much faster and less expensive. That way your feature tests will be less brittle, and it is easier to change the messages if you need to.